# Laravel Payum Omnipay Bridge Logic Exception

Tags: laravel, payment-gateway, omnipay, payum

I've been getting this error from omnipay bridge whenever I try to capture credit card payment:

```
Credit card details has to be set explicitly or there has to be an action that supports ObtainCreditCard request.
```

Here's my code:

```
//...
$payum = (new PayumBuilder())
    ->addDefaultStorages()
    ->addGateway('paymentexpress_pxpost', ['factory' => 'omnipay_paymentexpress_pxpost', 'username' => 'some_username', 'password'=>'some_password'])
    ->getPayum();

$card = [
    'number'      => $request->input('cc_number'), 
    'expiryMonth' => $request->input('expiry_month'),
    'expiryYear'  => $request->input('expiry_year'),
    'cvv'         => $request->input('cvv'),
    'name'        => $request->input('card_name')
];

$payment = new ArrayObject(['amount' => '1.00', 'currency' => 'AUD', 'card' => $card]);

if ($reply = $payum->getGateway('paymentexpress_pxpost')->execute(new Capture($payment), true)) {
    // convert reply to http response
}
//...
```

The `->execute()` function is the one that throws an error. I also referred to the same issue from [Error: Credit card details has to be set explicitly or there has to be an action that supports ObtainCreditCard request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27777599/error-credit-card-details-has-to-be-set-explicitly-or-there-has-to-be-an-action).

Comment: Why do you create a new payum builder instead of using the one from laravel package. The one from package have some additional stuff set (like obtain credit card action).

Answer (score 0):

Why do you create a new payum builder instead of using the one from laravel package. The one from package have some additional stuff set (like obtain credit card action).

Accoding to the [docs](https://github.com/Payum/PayumLaravelPackage/blob/master/docs/get-it-started.md) you should do something like this

```
App::resolving('payum.builder', function(\Payum\Core\PayumBuilder $payumBuilder) {
    $payumBuilder
        ->addGateway('paymentexpress_pxpost', [
            'factory' => 'omnipay_paymentexpress_pxpost', 
            'username' => 'some_username',
            'password'=>'some_password'
        ])
    ;
});
```

Comment: Update: I'm now using the pxpay instead of pxpost. I've added that in the provider. And ran into a new issue. InvalidArgumentException in HttpRedirect.php line 41:
Cannot redirect to an empty URL.. Seems like it's not genarating a correct URL though the payum tokens are generated.

Comment: maybe a bug in the paymentexpress omnipay extension?